# Put XSL-FO table on same page instead of moving it across next page

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo, xmltable

I am using XSL -FO  templates to generate PDF from xsl.In my PDF , I am having some tables which will be populated by dynamic data(no control over the rows that are generated). I am having some static content in the PDF after which the table is expected.The current behavior is something like, in the pdf , if the static content occupies till the middle of the page, and the table having dynamic content has got many number of rows, the table is getting shifted to the next page , leaving the space after static content blank. I want the behavior to be something like ,in the PDF , the table should start immediately after the static content in the same page and allow the permissible no of the rows in that page and continue the table in the next page if the table doesn't fit the previous page.

I am adding the code hereby for better clarity.

```
 <fo:block>
    <fo:block>
        <fo:table xsl:use-attribute-sets="tablestyle1">
        <fo:table-column xsl:use-attribute-sets="tablecoll" />
        <fo:table-column xsl:use-attribute-sets="tablecoll"/>
        <fo:table-column xsl:use-attribute-sets="tablecoll" />
        <fo:table-column xsl:use-attribute-sets="tablecoll" />
        <fo:table-column xsl:use-attribute-sets="tablecoll" />
            <fo:table-body>
                <fo:table-row xsl:use-attribute-sets="tabletr">
                    <fo:table-cell font-weight="bold" xsl:use-attribute-sets="tabletd">
                        <fo:block>
                            <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&#xA;</xsl:text>
                        </fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:table-cell font-weight="bold" xsl:use-attribute-sets="tabletd">
                        <fo:block>Name</fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                    ( 3 more cells here..)
                </fo:table-row>


                <xsl:for-each
                    select="(value is being fetched from function)">
                    <fo:table-row xsl:use-attribute-sets="tabletr">
                        <fo:table-cell font-weight="bold" xsl:use-attribute-sets="tabletd">
                            <fo:block>
                                <xsl:value-of select="position()" />
                            </fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>

                        <fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="tabletd">
                            <fo:block>
                                <xsl:choose>
                                    <xsl:when
                                        test="./Name/Title!='' or ./Name/ForeName !='' or ./Name/SecondInitial!='' or ./Name/Surname!=''">
                                        <xsl:call-template name="format-name1">
                                            <xsl:with-param name="name" select="./Name/Title" />
                                        </xsl:call-template>
                                        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                                        <xsl:call-template name="format-name1">
                                            <xsl:with-param name="name" select="./Name/ForeName" />
                                        </xsl:call-template>
                                        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                                        <xsl:call-template name="format-name1">
                                            <xsl:with-param name="name" select="./Name/Surname" />
                                        </xsl:call-template>
                                    </xsl:when>
                                    <xsl:otherwise>
                                        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&#xA;</xsl:text>
                                    </xsl:otherwise>
                                </xsl:choose>
                            </fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="tabletd">
                            (few more table cells are populated here using for - each iteration)
                            .
                            .
                            </fo:table-cell>
                            </fo:table-body>
        </fo:table>
    </fo:block>
</fo:block>
```

Comment: Show your attempt at coding this. Provide a [mcve]

Comment: Alan, the code has been added

Comment: In the tabletd attribute-set you call, there are probably attributes that handle pagination. (keep-with-next, keep-with-previous etc). Setting those to the wrong values will give the behavior you describe.

Comment: As @Hobbes said, we'd need to see at least the definitions of the `tablestyle1` and `tabletr` attribute sets to really know what is going on.  Also, when you say 'static content', do you mean areas generated from an `fo:static-content` or boilerplate text or what? (I don't think that you mean `fo:static-content`, since it shouldn't behave as you describe, but I'd like to check all the same.)

Comment: Any of the Keep attributes are not privided in td/tr calls.

Comment: <xsl:attribute-set name="tablestyle1" foa:class="table">
  <xsl:attribute name="font-size">1em</xsl:attribute>
  <xsl:attribute name="background-color">#E3E2E2</xsl:attribute>
  <xsl:attribute name="margin">10px</xsl:attribute>
 </xsl:attribute-set>

Comment: <xsl:attribute-set name="tabletr" foa:class="table">
  <xsl:attribute name="background-color">#ccc</xsl:attribute>
  <xsl:attribute name="keep-with-next">always</xsl:attribute>
 </xsl:attribute-set>

Comment: By the static content means some boiler plate text related to the end user.Its nothing related to fo:static-content.I am expecting the table to soon immediately after the content and continue to next page if it does not fit the current page.

Comment: There's still too many unknowns in the code that you provide.  Can you edit your answer to add a minimal sample of your XSL-FO output that doesn't break for you?  How many table rows would fit in the space after the boilerplate text?  Also, you don't need the two outer `fo:block`.

Answer (score 1):

Bingo:

```
<xsl:attribute-set name="tabletr" foa:class="table"> 
    <xsl:attribute name="keep-with-next">always</xsl:attribute>
```

the "always" setting is your culprit. This makes all rows of the table want to keep together. The formatter will try and place the entire table on one page.

You can either remove the attribute entirely, or change "always" to a number. keep-with settings use priorities, so start with a low priority number (1).